# Dynamically Spring AOP in Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using Eclipse Juno IDE.

I have a java application.

In the program I have those classes: Team.java Player.java
Now I'm enabling the user to add a new player to the team, the user gives me the player data.
and for each player there is a log file.

Now when the player is added to the team an event is occur "Player was added to the team"
what i want to do is to log this event and write what occur in the player's log file.

I want to handle those logging issues with Spring AOP. so how it can be done?

All the examples I saw are using with applicationContext.xml file. what I need to write
in this file, if the players are create dynamically?

Comment: Please clarify your question. I do not understand what you want. And I cannot make a smart comment on your XML file, not having seen it. ;-)

Comment: Hi Kriegaex! I eddited my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some tutorials make you believe Spring is used to define dependencies between value objects, like `House` bean has dependency on `Door` and `Heating` beans, etc. - typical Spring application is not built like that. Beans are normally used to declare stateless, singleton services, once and for good. There isn't much dynamic stuff going around after bootstrap.

However you *can* use Spring in your example. Just define player as prototype, lazy initialized bean:

```
<bean class="Player" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true"/>
```

And every time you need a new `Player`, ask container for it:

```
applicationContext.getBean(Player.class);
```

Returned bean will be fully functioning Spring bean, except that Spring won't call `@PreDestroy` callback. But AOP will work.

Comment: @eliorsh: if the players *are created dynamically* (using `new` operator in some code you have no control over), all you can do is go for load- or compile-time weaving (LTW/CTW) + Spring.

Comment: Tomasz,But if i create my own annotation (interface) and annotate this interface with @retention(runtime) .. it will work?

Comment: Tomasz thank you so much! your suggestion to use the prototype is  a great solution! but i didn't understand what did you mean with LTW/CTW? what is it? do you have any examples?

Comment: @eliorsh: I am not following, what annotation? How would it help you? If code you have no control over creates your `Player` object, you must use LTW/CTW to intercept that process.

Comment: @eliorsh: LTW/CTW is a heavyweight technology you can use to apply AOP by modifying bytecode. If `prototype` scope works for you, forget about it ;-).

Comment: Hi Tomasz, for the first experience with AOP, I read this tutorial 
http://thoughtforge.net/665/creating-a-logging-aspect-with-spring-aop-and-aspectj/

In this tutorial, he have a class annotated as aspect
and some interface that he created and used as a pointcut..

Now when he want to log some method or something.. he annotate the method with the annotation he created (the interface..)

Comment: LTW = load-time weaving. CTW = compile-time weaving. Google this, maybe in connection with an AspectJ tutorial. There should be plenty material online. I know this is not an answer, which is why I am just posting it as a comment.